# Em OOP, quais são as diferenças entre Acoplamento Aferente e Acoplamento Eferente?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, uml

Com relação ao conceito de `acoplamento` em `Programação Orientada a Objetos`, quais são as diferenças entre `Acoplamento Aferente` e `Acoplamento Eferente`? Se possível, para elucidar melhor o entendimento, como seria um possível exemplo de código e/ou `diagrama de classes`sobre eles?

Answer (score 1):

`O acoplamento aferente (Ca) representa a contagem de quantas classes diferentes referem-se à classe atual, por meio de campos ou parâmetros.`

Por exemplo, tenho uma classe `Animal` e as classes `Pessoa` e `Jaula`.
As classes `Pessoa` e `Jaula` tem um campo do tipo `Animal`. São duas classes que referem-se à classe `Animal`. O acoplamento aferente da classe `Animal` é 2 porque duas classes referenciam esta primeira.

```
public class Pessoa {
   public Animal animal;
}

public class Jaula {
    public Animal animal;
}

public class Animal {

}
```

`O acoplamento eferente (Ce) representa a contagem de quantas classes diferentes a classe atual faz referência, por meio de campos ou parâmetros.`

Por exemplo, tenho uma classe `Professor` e as classes `Sala` e `Materia`. A classe professor faz referencia às classes `Sala` e `Materia`. Logo o acoplamento de Professor é 2 pois ele referencia duas classes.

```
public class Sala {
}

public class Materia {
}

public class Professor {
    public Materia materia;
    public Sala sala;
}
```

Fonte: [Medindo Acoplamento](http://leandrodaniel.com/index.php/code-metrics-parte-3-medindo-acoplamento/)

Answer (score 1):

> O acoplamento entre classes ou subsistemas é uma medida da
>   interconexão entre essas classes ou subsistemas. Sendo assim,
>   acoplamento forte significa que as classes relacionadas precisam
>   conhecer detalhes internos umas das outras, as alterações se propagam
>   pelo sistema, e o sistema é potencialmente mais difícil de entender.
>
> Em resumo, as metas por trás da obtenção de um acoplamento fraco entre
>   classes e módulos são:
>
> - Tornar o código mais fácil de ler;
> - Tornar nossas classes mais simples para o consumo de outros desenvolvedores, ocultando a parte feia” do funcionamento interno em
>     APIs bem projetadas;
> - Isolar possíveis alterações em uma área pequena do código;
> - Reutilizar classes em contextos completamente novos.

(Fonte: [Code metrics](http://leandrodaniel.com/index.php/code-metrics-parte-3-medindo-acoplamento/))

O **acoplamento aferente** (Ca) faz a contagem do número de classificadores fora de um pacote que referencia um classificador dentro do pacote. Se esse número for alto, essa classe tem a alta chance de ser estável, diminuindo o risco do acoplamento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O **acoplamento eferente** (Ce) faz a contagem do número de classificadores em um pacote diferente que um classificador dentro de um pacote de referências. Se uma classe possui acoplamento eferente alto, isso significa que ela depende de muitas classes.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segundo o [Elemar Jr](http://elemarjr.com/pt/2014/10/21/static-analysis-101-parte-2-acoplamento-aferente-e-acoplamento-eferente-com-ndepend/):

> Tipos com alto acoplamento eferente são mais difíceis de testar. Além
>   disso, são mais "sensíveis" a modificações do sistema. Aqueles com
>   alto acoplamento aferente costumam impactar de forma mais séria o
>   sistema quando não funcionam adequadamente.

No site da IBM, você encontra outras [métricas na categoria de acoplamento](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/pt-br/SS8PJ7_8.5.1/com.ibm.xtools.analysis.modelanalysis.doc/topics/rmetricsformodelanalysis.html):

> - Abstratividade: Esta métrica calcula a proporção das classes abstratas e de interface para o número total de classes no pacote.
> - Instabilidade: Esta métrica calcula a proporção de acoplamento eferente para o acoplamento total (aferente mais eferente).
> - Distância normal: Esta métrica calcula a distância normalizada para a sequência principal. A sequência principal é onde a abstratividade e
>     instabilidade são equilibradas.

Referência:

- [Code metrics](http://leandrodaniel.com/index.php/code-metrics-parte-3-medindo-acoplamento/)
- [Orientação a objetos: uma outra perspectiva sobre o acoplamento](http://blog.caelum.com.br/orientacao-a-objetos-uma-outra-perspectiva-sobre-o-acoplamento/)
- [Entendendo Coesão e Acoplamento](http://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-coesao-e-acoplamento/18538)

Answer (score 0):

Opa!

Basicamente a diferença está no ponto de vista em relação a classe à qual será feita esta análise. 
Explico:

*Vamos levar como exemplo a classe "Exemplo"*

**Acoplamento eferente:** Digamos que a classe exemplo precise enviar um e-mail e postar alguma informação em uma API. Caso esteja com um design ruim, esta classe terá dependência eferente a estas dua classes:

```
class Exemplo{
   ClienteEmail clienteEmail;
   ClienteApi clienteApi;
}
```

Ou seja, a classe Exemplo possui acoplamento eferente às classes ClienteEmail e ClienteApi.

**Acoplamento aferente** são as classes que utilizam a "classe Exemplo", exemplo:

```
class Aplicacao{
   Exemplo exemplo;
}

class Teste{
   Exemplo exemplo;
}
```

Ou seja, tanto Aplicacao quanto Teste possuem acoplamento aferente à classe Exemplo.

Sei que foram *toy examples* e eu sei o quão não aplicáveis estes exemplos são, mas espero ter elucidado um pouco sua dúvida.

Uma explicação melhor detalhada você encontra aqui:
http://leandrodaniel.com/index.php/code-metrics-parte-3-medindo-acoplamento/